# What is Queryxchange.com? Is it spam or some child website to SE?

Tags: support

At [this](https://www.queryxchange.com/) website, I could see all my SE posted questions, where I was automatically logged in to my FB account. I don't remember registering myself for this website.

Is it some child website to SE or is it some spam? I am worried as I did not register myself for SE also with my FB account. How could it get my details??

Examples:

1. My question on [SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/345817/dali-multi-master-how-to-design-a-multi-master-system-is-it-part-of-dali-stand)   vs [Qxchange](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/26_345817/dali-multi-master-how-to-design-a-multi-master-system-is-it-part-of-dali-standard/)
2. My question on [SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340987/dali-communication-is-dali-protocol-a-byte-transfer-mechanism-or-packet-layer-m) vs [Qxchange](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/26_340987/dali-communication-is-dali-protocol-a-byte-transfer-mechanism-or-packet-layer-mechanism/)

In fact, complete EEexchange is getting updated at [this](https://www.queryxchange.com/c/26-electronicsxchanger/) link.

PS: I am not quite sure where to ask this question. It is valid in general for complete SE but I am mostly active in EEexchange, so I thought it would be appropriate to ask here!

EDIT: Finally got the time to go through the link given and found out that it fails to attribute to SE visually anywhere on the site and it is claiming the copyright to this site's content at the bottom of the page! I have flagged it to SE through the contact form and also to Google as guided. Please take two minutes and flag this website.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Comment: Well done on spotting and flagging it. Just wanted to add while it's probably worth multiple people flagging it with Google the contact form sends a message to an employee where they add it to a list so there's no point in anyone else doing that step.

Comment: I did not get you clearly! I do not know any Google employees.

Comment: I meant the "SE contact form" goes to an SE employee, so there's not any point anyone else doing that now they know about it.

Comment: I requested everyone to do that because after flagging it to SE, I got an email saying that "Due to the nature of this request and the amount of time it takes to process them, it is unlikely that you will receive any further follow-up emails regarding this issue.". I believe it will be quicker through Google, if many flag it! Maybe you are right, I am not quite sure how it works with SE.

Comment: They don't seem to copy the comments... that's going to lead a lot of people up the garden path... LOL

Answer (score 1):

It's legal to copy the information here, under certain circumstances. Some details about that can be found in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/334517). In short - the information you post here is published under a free license.

I don't know how Facebook is involved or how it is relevant to that website, I don't understand what you mean by this. I block everything having to do with Facebook, they are extremely intrusive.